Excel formula to validate columns in a range?
I'm having some issues putting together a formula to validate numbers between two columns within a range with criteria.
Example:
I have the following in a spreadsheet

I'd like  to setup a conditional format where in column A if E and J matches then the entire Range for A where the FlexKey matches gets highlighted green.  However if even one item doesn't match it would be unhighlighted.
So essentially it would return this as a result:

I've tried a few different formulas I know but not having any success:
Formula 1:
=AND(SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,A2)<>J2)

This just returns true to everything
Formula 2:
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,J:J,J2)

This returns true false by row but not by column A's ID number.
I know I'm close but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Don't work on the entire column at once. The condition works on each row one at a time. try =AND(E2=J2,E2<>"",J2<>"") and apply the condition to column A

Appreciate the response! If I do each row I get the same result as my countifs which is what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want any highlighting if even one row is wrong where the ID's match. Ultimately I'm hoping to use a filter to hide those items that match.

Try the following condition:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),--(E:E=J:J))=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)

It counts how many rows exists with the same FlexKey and where Columns A and E match, then compares it to the number of rows with the Flexkey. If the two match then all instances of a Flexkey have columns E and J match, otherwise it returns false.
A simple example:


Thought there would be a more succinct method than mine - very nice!

Thank you! this is perfect. Really appreciate your help!

If columns E and J contain numbers or blanks, you could also try:
=IF(A2<>"",LET(f,FILTER(A:J,A:A=A2),SUM(CHOOSECOLS(f,5)-CHOOSECOLS(f,10)))=0)



I'd look to build a list of FlexKeys which should be green, which can then be searched by the conditional formula.
You could start with a simple column (col M for me) which is just E2=J2 in M2 etc.
In Col O, I put =FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))). This is just a list of FlexKeys in Col A, filtering out empty entries.
In Col P, I put =FILTER(M:M,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))). This gives the TRUE/FALSE for each respective entry.
In Col R, I put =UNIQUE(O2#). This removes duplicate entries of FlexKeys.
In Col S, I put =BYROW(R2#, LAMBDA(row, AND(FILTER(P2#,O2#=row)))). For each FlexKey, this will return TRUE if all entries have E=J, and so should be green.
Finally, in Col U, I put =FILTER(R2#,S2#=TRUE). This filters the list of FlexKeys so only 'green' entries are returned. Alternatively, you could collate the helper columns to use (as is in Col V for me):
=FILTER(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))),BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))),
LAMBDA(row,
AND(FILTER(FILTER(M:M,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))=row))))=TRUE)

You can then use =OR(A1=$V$2#) as a conditional formula, where V2# refers to your list of 'green FlexKeys' you have generated above.

